# Facing Issues with LDAP-Login when using in Python

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I am using flask_ldap3_login to login via authentication from Active Directory. Code is provided below for reference.

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager, AuthenticationResponseStatus
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, UserMixin, current_user
from flask import render_template_string, redirect
from flask_ldap3_login.forms import LDAPLoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# Setup LDAP Configuration Variables. Change these to your own settings.
# All configuration directives can be found in the documentation.

# Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldap://x.x.x.x'

# Base DN of your directory 
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'OU=City Name,OU=Team Name,OU=Users,OU=Country,OU=Sites,DC=domain,DC=com'
# app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'DC=domain,DC=com'

# Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
# app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'OU=Users,OU=Country'

# Groups DN to be prepended to the Base DN
# app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'OU=City,OU=Team Name'

# The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP
# app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'

# The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with.
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'sAMAccountName'

# The Username to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = 'CN=Name,OU=city,OU=Team,OU=Users,OU=country,OU=Sites,DC=domain,DC=com'

# The Password to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

login_manager = LoginManager(app)              # Setup a Flask-Login Manager
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)          # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager.

@app.route('/manual_login', methods=['POST'])
def manual_login():
      result = app.ldap3_login_manager.authenticate('user`enter code here`', 'password')
    print(result.status)
    return 'fail' if result.status == AuthenticationResponseStatus.fail else 'success'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Then issue is, when I am using the complete **app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN']** as mentioned above then it's working fine but in case when I am using only **DC=domain,DC=com** as Base_DN to authenticate users from the whole organization then returning me **fail** rather than **Success**

Answer (score 4):

You need to set  scope to `SUBTREE` :

```
app.config['LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE'] = 'SUBTREE'
```

The default is `LEVEL` in ldap3 (cf. [documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/searches.html) - seems flask-ldap3 implementation does not mention it though) :

- `BASE`: retrieves attributes of the entry specified in the search_base.
- `LEVEL`: retrieves attributes of the entries contained in the search_base. The base must reference a container object.
- `SUBTREE`: retrieves attributes of the entries specified in the search_base and all subordinate containers downward.

---

For those still having the issue even after having properly set `LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE`, you need to set `LDAP_ALWAYS_SEARCH_BIND` to a non empty value (#undocumented) :

```
app.config['LDAP_ALWAYS_SEARCH_BIND'] = 1
```

otherwise ldap3 will make the assumption that [*"Since the user's RDN is the same as the login field, it can do a direct bind."*](https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login/blob/master/flask_ldap3_login/__init__.py#L251) which will only work if user's RDN are one `LEVEL` down the `<user-base-dn>,<base-dn>`, but not further in the `SUBTREE`.

Comment: For me only the `'SUBTREE'` attribute worked, then I achieved the `AuthenticationResponseStatus.success` status